# Navigator.getUserMedia en Ios no funciona, si en android

Tags: jquery

Muy buenas, tengo el siguiente código en el que lanzo la camara para capturar una imagen, en android funciona bien pero en Ios (Safari) No me parecece la imagen de la camara. Tampoco me pregunta por los permisos de uso. Me gustaría saber como podría usar este código tambien en Ios. Gracias.

```
//Boton que lanza la camara
     $('#btnVideoIni').on( "click", function() {     
        $("#videoCam").css("display", "block");
            $video.play();
        });

    //Archivo js al que llamo al inicio
    var tieneSoporteUserMedia = () =>
        !!(navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
     var _getUserMedia = (...arguments) =>
        (navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).apply(navigator, arguments);

    // Declaramos elementos del DOM
     var $video = document.querySelector("#videoCam"),
        $canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

     var obtenerDispositivos = () => navigator
        .mediaDevices
        .enumerateDevices();
    (

    function() {
        // Comenzamos viendo si tiene soporte, si no, nos detenemos
        if (!tieneSoporteUserMedia()) {
            alert("Lo siento. Tu navegador no soporta esta característica");
            inf( "Parece que tu navegador no soporta esta característica. Intenta actualizarlo.","0");
            return;
        }
        //Aquí guardaremos el stream globalmente
        let stream;

     // Comenzamos pidiendo los dispositivos
        obtenerDispositivos()
            .then(dispositivos => {
                // Vamos a filtrarlos y guardar aquí los de vídeo
                var dispositivosDeVideo = [];

                // Recorrer y filtrar
                dispositivos.forEach(function(dispositivo) {
                    var tipo = dispositivo.kind;
                    if (tipo === "videoinput") {
                        dispositivosDeVideo.push(dispositivo);
                    }

                });

                if(dispositivosDeVideo[1]==undefined){
                     mostrarStream(dispositivosDeVideo[0].deviceId);
                }
                else{
                     mostrarStream(dispositivosDeVideo[1].deviceId);
                }
    });


    var mostrarStream = idDeDispositivo => {
            _getUserMedia({
                    video: {
                        // Justo aquí indicamos cuál dispositivo usar
                        deviceId: idDeDispositivo,
                    }
                },
                (streamObtenido) => {

                    stream = streamObtenido;
                    // Mandamos el stream de la cámara al elemento de vídeo
                    $video.srcObject = stream;
                   // $video.play();
                    //Escuchar el click del botón para tomar la foto


                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
                    inf( "No se puede acceder a la cámara, o no diste permiso.","0");
                });
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `navigator.getUserMedia()` está deprecado y no arroja compatibilidad con *Safari* en *IOS*.

En su lugar puedes usar el método `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` que arroja una mayor compatibilidad y se trata de la alternativa actual a `navigator.getUserMedia()`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
// Prefer camera resolution nearest to 1280x720.
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.
```

**Referencias:** [navigator.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia), [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)